# Winforms on .net core: ConfigurationManager

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.0

It looks quite easy to port winforms app to .net core 3 but is there a recommended way to Port call to the configuration manager / convert app.config files ? It looks like it's still possible to call the configurationManager but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Actually some sections only are not compatible. I just had to remove one section referencing a webservice

Comment: What do you wish: calling `ConfigurationManager` in .NET core or convert to `app.config` into a .NET core equivalent ?

Comment: I was looking for best practices documentation. I thought it wasn't working because of unrecognized section, but now I can see it's working.